# Using aggregation function to filter record based on MIN timestamp

Tags: oracle, join, aggregate-functions, min

```
SELECT * FROM ABC_CUSTOMER_DETAILS abc_detail
INNER JOIN ABC_CUSTOMERS abc_cust
ON abc_detail.ID=abc_cust.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE abc_detail.COUNTRY_CODE='KE'
AND CREATION_TIMESTAMP=(SELECT MIN (CREATION_TIMESTAMP)
                        FROM ABC_CUSTOMER_DETAILS abc_detail
                        INNER JOIN ABC_CUSTOMERS abc_cust
                        ON abc_detail.ID=abc_cust.CUSTOMER_ID
                        WHERE abc_detail.COUNTRY_CODE='KE');
```

Above script query join record from `ABC_CUSTOMER_DETAILS` to `ABC_CUSTOMERS` nd select thw one with earliest timestamp.

Anyway if I able not to repeat the same `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause in `CREATION_TIMESTAMP` condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get the earliest record and to avoid having to type the same criteria twice.

**Using FETCH FIRST ROWS (available as of Oracle 12c)**

```
select * 
from abc_customer_details cd
join abc_customers c on c.id = cd.customer_id
where cd.country_code = 'KE'
order by creation_timestamp
fetch first row only;
```

**Using a CTE (WITH clause)**

```
with cte as
(
  select * 
  from abc_customer_details cd
  join abc_customers c on c.id = cd.customer_id
  where cd.country_code = 'KE'
)
select *
from cte
where (creation_timestamp) = (select min(creation_timestamp) from cte);
```

**Using window functions**

```
select *
from
(
  select cd.*, c.*, min(creation_timestamp) over () as min_creation_timestamp
  from abc_customer_details cd
  join abc_customers c on c.id = cd.customer_id
  where cd.country_code = 'KE'
)
where creation_timestamp = min_creation_timestamp;
```

(I changed the join criteria in all these queries, by the way. It just does seem extremely unlikely you want to join on `abc_customer_details.id = abc_customers.customer_id`.)

Comment: The CTE (WITH clause) work perfectly on 11g, but one of the column in my select is sequence, `abc_customer_details.nextval`. This line is recognised here  `sequence number not allowed here`

Comment: The 3rd query needs an `OVER` clause to work. Moreover, I assumed from the question the op wanted `MIN` of each group. But, that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Kaushik Nayak: Thanks; I've added the missing `OVER` clause.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, anyway if 2nd query able to work with `sequence.nextval` ?

Comment: I don't know, how exactly you want to apply the sequence. Just pull its next value like in `select cte.*, mysequence.nextval`? That should work. But why would you do that? We are using sequences to get IDs for inserts; why do you want a sequence in this query?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner i am using this select statement to insert a new record to `ABC_CUSTOMER_DETAILS`, the sequence is the PK and need to be  in nextval.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `MIN()` analytic function.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            abc_detail.*,
            abc_cust.*,
            MIN(creation_timestamp) OVER(
                PARTITION BY abc_detail.id
            ) AS min_timestamp
        FROM
            abc_customer_details abc_detail
            INNER JOIN abc_customers abc_cust
        ON abc_detail.id = abc_cust.customer_id
        WHERE
            abc_detail.country_code = 'KE'
    )
WHERE
    creation_timestamp = min_timestamp;
```

Comment: I am getting `ORA-00904: "CREATION_TIMESTAMP": invalid identifier`'

Comment: @user2102665: Kaushik Nayak is selecting all columns from the two tables. In your own query you are using `CREATION_TIMESTAMP`. So if this results in an error, you must have been mistaken with this column.

Comment: @user2102665 : Do you want to compare with `MIN` among each group `(CUSTOMER_ID)` or `MIN()`  of the whole result-set?

Comment: @ Kaushik Nayak, i want to compare `MIN` amoung each of the `CREATION_TIMESTAMP` column in  `ABC_CUSTOMER_DETAILS`table

Comment: @user2102665: No, what Kaushik Nayak means is: Do you want the one oldest customer / detail row or do you want the oldest detail row per customer?

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak@Thorsten Kettner  oldest detail row per customer plz