# Column name become invalid after referred as result of aggregate function MIN()

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, min, ora-00904

```
SELECT cust_detl.*, 
       MIN(CREATION_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) AS MIN_TIMESTAMP
FROM CUST_DETAILS cust_detl
WHERE CREATION_TIMESTAMP=MIN_TIMESTAMP;
```

Above query select all columns from table `CUST_DETAILS` with oldest value in`CREATION_TIMESTAMP` column.

Any idea why `MIN_TIMESTAMP` encounter as an invalid identifier?

These are the columns that should display:

```
SELECT
  CUSTOMER_DTL_SEQ.nextval,
  CUST_ID
  CUS_REF_ID
  CUST_NAME
  CUST_ADDRESS
  CREATION_TIMESTAMP
FROM
(
  CUSTOMER_DTL_SEQ.nextval,
   cust_detl.CUST_ID,
   cust_detl.CUST_REF_ID,
   cust_detl.CUST_NAME,
   cust_detl.CUST_ADDRESS,
   cust_detl.CREATION_TIMESTAMP,
    MIN(CREATION_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) AS min_timestamp
    FROM cust_details cust_detl
  )
 WHERE CREATION_TIMESTAMP = min_timestamp;
```

I would need to select `CREATION_TIMESTAMP` column as well, only those columns with minimum timestamp will be selected. The problem is the sequence with `nextval` is not allowed. I would need sequence in the query as this statment is going to use for `INSERT` later `SELECT...INSERT INTO`

The PK need to be incremented.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50461060/1509264 - if the OP's focus is on a working query then this should be closed as a duplicate; however, if the OP's focus is on **why** the query does not work then answers should focus on that question and this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The column name is not yet valid, data is filtered first with the where condition and then on the filtered data, select statement works. You need to put it in sub query before you can use it.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT cust_detl.*, 
        MIN(CREATION_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) AS MIN_TIMESTAMP
   FROM CUST_DETAILS cust_detl)
WHERE CREATION_TIMESTAMP=MIN_TIMESTAMP;
```

**UPDATE:** I don't know what list of columns you have in your table, but if you need only specific columns, then the query goes like this(assuming you need only columns cust_id, column1, column2 and column3 in select list)

```
SELECT cust_id,
       column1,
       column2,
       column3
  FROM (SELECT cust_detl.cust_id,
               cust_detl.column1,
               cust_detl.column2,
               cust_detl.column3,
               cust_detl.creation_timestamp,
               MIN(creation_timestamp) over(PARTITION BY cust_id) AS min_timestamp
          FROM cust_details cust_detl)
 WHERE creation_timestamp = min_timestamp;
```

If you still don't get your solution, the post the list of columns from the table and the expected output.

**Update2** : Fetch the cursor in the outer query, this query should work fine.

```
SELECT customer_dtl_seq.nextval,
       cust_id,
       cus_ref_id, 
       cust_name,
       cust_address,
       creation_timestamp
  FROM (SELECT cust_detl.cust_id,
               cust_detl.cust_ref_id,
               cust_detl.cust_name,
               cust_detl.cust_address,
               cust_detl.creation_timestamp,
               MIN(creation_timestamp) over(PARTITION BY cust_id) AS min_timestamp
          FROM cust_details cust_detl)
 WHERE creation_timestamp = min_timestamp;
```

Comment: i tried with `cust_detl.*`, it return multiple record but the one with min timestamp. if wihout it, `CREATION_TIMESTAMP`column become invalid. Can I fix with only certain columns are selected instead of select all columns?

Comment: @user2102665 : I gave you the solution here. But you did not pay attention https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461060/using-aggregation-function-to-filter-record-based-on-min-timestamp . You have to add the column names in the inner select list for it to be visible outside the sub-query. You are missing it in your select and you are not showing it to us.

Comment: @San, added the respected columns and expected result.